# Unknown IP addresses in Amazon S3 Bucket access logs

Tags: amazon-s3

I have enabled S3 access logs on a bucket. All the entries are from my EC2 instance except a few which are from unknown private IP address. These IPs have addresses like 10.x.x.x. Is it some kind of malicious activity?

Answer (score 0):

10.x.x.x could be internal, could also be malicious. best to be on the safe side and make sure, just change your access details and scan your computer for anything that could be sniffing for thos details.

Comment: How, by any chance, an ip from 10.x.x.x could not be internal?

Comment: sorry, should have explained a little better. it could be something as simple as an internal check that means nothing. it could be a member of the security team checking out your content (dont know if amazon do that), it could be another of your EC2 instances logging in. it could be that somebody made their way into a vpn on your account, and used that to mask their real ip when accessing your instance. it could be one of many things. my suggestion is to review your security policy as a whole